# Restore input values with Shiny URL bookmark and rerun calculations

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a use case for a shiny app where the users can enter some value and when clicked on run it would run a model and show the values in the table. Now when I click on bookmark it captures the input values. And when I click on the restore bookmark it does populate the input values. What I want to do is after it restores the input values it should also run the model again and populate the values in the table. In short restore bookmark should populate the values and click on the run button to run the model.How can this be achieved ?

Below is the code for bookmark :

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
    column(
      12,
      column(3,tags$div(title="forecast", numericInput("budget_input", label = ("Total Forecast"), value = 2))),
      column(2, textInput(inputId = "description", label = "Bookmark description", placeholder = "Data Summary")),
      column(2, bookmarkButton(id="bookmarkBtn"))),
    column(2, actionButton("opt_run", "Run")),
    DT::dataTableOutput("urlTable", width = "100%"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#bookmarkBtn { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "bookmarks.db", overwrite = FALSE)
  myBookmarks <- reactiveValues(urlDF = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })

  observeEvent(input$opt_run, {
    output$x1 = renderDT(df %>% mutate(Current  = as.numeric(Current)*(input$budget_input)), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
  })

  if(dbExistsTable(con, "Bookmarks")){
    tmpUrlDF <- data.table(dbReadTable(con, "Bookmarks"))
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- tmpUrlDF[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct(Timestamp, origin="1970-01-01 00:00")]
  } else {
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- NULL
  }

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    tmpUrlDF <- isolate({myBookmarks$urlDF})
    if(!is.null(tmpUrlDF)){
       dbWriteTable(con, "Bookmarks", tmpUrlDF, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
     dbDisconnect(con)
  })

  setBookmarkExclude(c("bookmarkBtn", "description", "urlTable_cell_clicked", "urlTable_rows_all", "urlTable_rows_current", "urlTable_rows_selected", "urlTable_search", "urlTable_state", "urlTable_row_last_clicked"))

  df <- data.table(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                   Current = c("2000", "3000","4000"),
                   Modified = c("2500", "3500","3000"),
                   New_Membership = c("450", "650","700"))

  output$x1 = renderDT(df, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)

  onBookmarked(fun=function(url){
    if(!url %in% myBookmarks$urlDF$URL){
      if(is.null(myBookmarks$urlDF)){
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")), by="URL")
      } else {
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(rbindlist(list(myBookmarks$urlDF, data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")))), by="URL")
      }
    }
  })

  output$urlTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(myBookmarks$urlDF)
    myBookmarks$urlDF[User %in% Sys.getenv("USERNAME")]
  }, escape=FALSE)

}
enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I haven't actually used this before, but does the `onBookmark` and `onRestore` from here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html help?

Comment: I get to the stage where it restores the values but doesn't  initiate `opt_run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct was that you probably need to use `onRestore()` as @AndrewTaylor suggested. But after trying to run your code, it was evident that the issue here is fixed by simply fixing the reactivity in the code.

Here is your code, with two small edits: first, the output$x1 was defined twice, so I removed the second one that was not using any reactive values. Secondly, I moved the first output$x1 to be outside of an observeEvent, and made it trigger only when the button is pressed. You should generally not define an output inside an observer, unless it's a special case where it's mandatory, but the way it was done here causes incorrect reactivity. Fixing this is all you needed.

Also, the `DT` and `dplyr` packages needed to be loaded to make the code fully reproducible.

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
    column(
      12,
      column(3,tags$div(title="forecast", numericInput("budget_input", label = ("Total Forecast"), value = 2))),
      column(2, textInput(inputId = "description", label = "Bookmark description", placeholder = "Data Summary")),
      column(2, bookmarkButton(id="bookmarkBtn"))),
    column(2, actionButton("opt_run", "Run")),
    DT::dataTableOutput("urlTable", width = "100%"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#bookmarkBtn { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "bookmarks.db", overwrite = FALSE)
  myBookmarks <- reactiveValues(urlDF = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })

  observeEvent(input$opt_run, {
    cat('HJE')
  })

  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$opt_run
    isolate({
      datatable(
        df %>% mutate(Current  = as.numeric(Current)*(input$budget_input)), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
      )
    })
  })

  if(dbExistsTable(con, "Bookmarks")){
    tmpUrlDF <- data.table(dbReadTable(con, "Bookmarks"))
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- tmpUrlDF[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct(Timestamp, origin="1970-01-01 00:00")]
  } else {
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- NULL
  }

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    tmpUrlDF <- isolate({myBookmarks$urlDF})
    if(!is.null(tmpUrlDF)){
      dbWriteTable(con, "Bookmarks", tmpUrlDF, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
    dbDisconnect(con)
  })

  setBookmarkExclude(c("bookmarkBtn", "description", "urlTable_cell_clicked", "urlTable_rows_all", "urlTable_rows_current", "urlTable_rows_selected", "urlTable_search", "urlTable_state", "urlTable_row_last_clicked"))

  df <- data.table(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                   Current = c("2000", "3000","4000"),
                   Modified = c("2500", "3500","3000"),
                   New_Membership = c("450", "650","700"))

  onBookmarked(fun=function(url){
    if(!url %in% myBookmarks$urlDF$URL){
      if(is.null(myBookmarks$urlDF)){
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")), by="URL")
      } else {
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(rbindlist(list(myBookmarks$urlDF, data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")))), by="URL")
      }
    }
  })

  output$urlTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(myBookmarks$urlDF)
    myBookmarks$urlDF[User %in% Sys.getenv("USERNAME")]
  }, escape=FALSE)

}
enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, this also fixes an issue you may have noticed where the table kept updating without even pressing the Run button after pressing Run for the first time. Correct reactivity is very important, otherwise you run into all sorts of weird issues!

Comment: This was just a reproducible example ,but in the app I am working on, i have a module to where I run  a model and the output table x1 is rendered. How do I use that same table in a different module for saving the bookmarks and restoring them ?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing an example. Your example does not have the problem you mention, as it was solved by solving the reactivity. If your real app can't be solved this way, then I suggest posting a new question or editing your post to include a minimal but reproducible example where with proper reactivity your issue still happens

Comment: I figured it out that I would need a minimum reproducible example.Thank you :)

Comment: I just added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835717/how-do-i-break-a-r-shiny-app-into-modules